# Angular 7 routing issue, routing to a specific page throws a error

Tags: angular

I have set up my routing for my webpage and I have a error that I cant work out. If i load the webpage from google www.epsomoddballs.org the page loads and then adds /home so the address is www.epsomoddballs.org/home but if i try and load www.epsomoddballs.org/home or refresh the page I get a error that the url cant be found.

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: "", redirectTo: "home", pathMatch: "full" },
  { path: "home", component: HomeComponent },
];

export const AppRoutingModule =
  RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { useHash: true });
```

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { MatFormFieldModule, MatSelectModule, MatDialogModule, MatTableModule, MatTabsModule, MatIconModule, MatPaginatorModule, MatInputModule } from "@angular/material";
import { AgmSnazzyInfoWindowModule } from '@agm/snazzy-info-window';
import { NgxTwitterTimelineModule } from 'ngx-twitter-timeline';
import { DxSchedulerModule } from 'devextreme-angular';
import { AgmCoreModule } from '@agm/core';
import { NgbModule } from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routing';
import { CommonModule, APP_BASE_HREF } from "@angular/common";
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { HomeComponent } from "../component/home/home.component";
import { FooterComponent } from "../component/footer/footer.component";
import { HeaderComponent } from "../component/header/header.component";
import { KitComponent } from "../component/Kit/kit.component";
import { ClubNewsComponent } from "../component/News/clubnews.component";
import { CalComponent } from "../component/Calendar/calendar.component";
import { MabacComponent } from '../component/MABAC/mabac.component';
import { MembershipComponent } from "../component/membership/membership.component";
import { RacesComponent } from "../component/races/races.component";
import { NewRunnerDialog } from "../component/home/NewRunnerText/new_runner_text";
import { TrainingComponent } from "../component/training/training.component";
import { SundayComponent } from '../component/training/Sunday/sunday.component';
import { ThursdayComponent } from '../component/training/thursday/thursday.component';
import { TrackComponent } from '../component/training/track/track.component';
import { TuesdayComponent } from '../component/training/tuesday/tuesday.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    ClubNewsComponent,
    CalComponent,
    MabacComponent,
    KitComponent,
    MembershipComponent,
    RacesComponent,
    SundayComponent,
    TrainingComponent,
    ThursdayComponent,
    TuesdayComponent,
    TrackComponent,
    NewRunnerDialog
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    DxSchedulerModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatInputModule,
    NgbModule,
    NgxTwitterTimelineModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AgmSnazzyInfoWindowModule,

  ],
  providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you imported your routing.module in app.module ?

Comment: Yes my routing module is in my app module.

Comment: Can you add code for your app.module here ?

Comment: @Techie_T added the app_module code above

Comment: press F12 on your chrome tab, what page/file is it trying to fetch that throws the 404 ? what's its full path ? also is there a reason you're manually providing `APP_BASE_HREF` ?

Comment: @Stavm Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) not to sure on the APP_BASE_HREF i thought I read you needed it.

Comment: you don't need it, also notice you're using `useHash: true` on your routes, that means you should be navigating to `www.epsomoddballs.org/#/home` and not just `/home`.

Comment: @Stavm so I can remove APP_BASE_HREF and then should I keep useHash: true or should it be false? All i want is if someone writes www.epsomoddballs.org/home the page will load not error.

Comment: if that's all you want, then remove the useHash ...

Comment: @Stavm remove it completely or make it false?

Comment: `RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);`

Answer (score 0):

Use a slash since you're using full path matching
`{ path: "", redirectTo: "/home", pathMatch: "full" },`

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply, but that hasnt made any difference.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is not related to configuring routes while this is related to **base href** config in index.html.

```
 <base href=”/”>
```

Please check your index.html file and put appropriate value for href.

Comment: Hi, are you suggesting that I have <base href=”/”> in my index.html, or i should put something after the "/"?

Comment: yes, did u deployed your application in the root directory or inside any folder?